# Can you still set the timeout for a lambda function in Serverless when it's in a container

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In normal lambdas, it's straightforward to set the timeout within the serverless.yml

For eg

```
functions:
  my_function:
    handler: handler.my_function
    timeout: 60
```

However when I use a container image, this seems to get lost and AWS uses the default of 6s. This is the example code:

```
functions:
  my_function:
    image:
      name: appimage
      command:
        - handler.my_function
    timeout: 60
```

Am I doing something wrong? I can of course set it manually on the AWS console, but it would be nice to have it all in the yml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why yes, yes you can.
Inside your `serverless.yml` add the following:
From the [docs:](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/)

```
provider:
  runtime: nodejsXX.x
  # Default timeout for functions (default: 6 seconds)
  # Note: API Gateway has a maximum timeout of 30 seconds
  timeout: 10
```

6 seconds is the default timeout, and the max timeout for is 30 seconds, so just add your timeout under provider chunk and you should be all set! You were close!

NOTE:
Keep in mind that API Gateway is the service that actually times out. Your lambda can still be running, and compete successfully, as [nascente-diskreta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17030712/nascente-diskreta) mentioned, for a long time after that.
The response will appear to timed out in the request cycle. I ran into this recently where jobs would return a failed response. But the lambda successfully completed. It just could not tell the server it had completed using API Gateway.

Comment: You are right that the max timeout is 30 seconds, but only for APIGateway (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300708/17030712 ). For Lambda functions, the timeout can go up to 15 minutes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html

Comment: You are absolutly right nascente_diskreta!

Comment: Updated the answer! I ran into this a few times. We havea a PDF created and uploader to S3, and would time out, but then succeed afterward.